# use inner join using with case statement in mysql select

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT ord.*,usr.*,ship.* FROM order_list ord
CASE 
WHEN shiptype = 'prof'
 THEN (INNER JOIN user_list usr 
      ON ord.userid = usr.id
      INNER JOIN user_list ship
      ON order.userid = ship.id)
WHEN shiptype = 'brief'
 THEN (INNER JOIN user_list usr 
      ON ord.userid = usr.id
      INNER JOIN tbl_brf_shipping ship
      ON order.userid = ship.id)
WHEN shiptype = 'joan'
 THEN (INNER JOIN joan_user_list usr 
      ON ord.userid = usr.id
      INNER JOIN joan_user_list ship
      ON order.userid = ship.id)
END
WHERE complete = '1'
```

it's not working ...........

Comment: give unique names for table bro, try it with ship1, ship2 instead, hope this helps

Comment: Please explain in a few words what are you trying to do ? The syntax of this query is totally incorrect, study this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html, there is no such thing in SQL like `conditional join to different tables`, the `CASE` keyword is not allowed after the `FROM tablename`, it is allowed only in expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but the query posted is incorrect.
What you seem to need is prepared statements: Prepare the query string and execute it separately.
Read more at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html